# What is the proper way to send images from an API to HTML?

Tags: java, html

My current implementation is the following:

I store the image in binary data in the Database. Then I load it and send it as Base64 data in the Http Response.

API:

```
    @Lob
    @Column(length = 16777215)
    private byte[] image;
```

Then load it in the UI `<img ng-src="data:image/png;base64, {{product.image}}">`

The HTTP Response is Huge for some images. It works well for a couple of images but let's say I want to display 100 images.

Is this the proper way to do it fast and well?

Comment: The proper way is to have a URL that returns an image (just like you would do for static images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just try passing the URL to API in the image node. For example:

```
<img ng-src="https://api.myhost.com/product/5646/image" />
```

In most cases it should work just fine.

Comment: But the image is stored in the database, not a file system. Should I just store the product url to the image and create a generic endpoint to expose the image?

Comment: @TiagoSilva the frontend doesn't know or care where the image is stored. It gets the bytes from over the network. The bytes can be even generated by an algorithm, so there's no stored image at all. But for this you need an endpoint that **only** returns the bytes for an image (like in the code in this answer), without Base64 encoding.

Comment: You might create an API that takes the `productId` as a parameter (e.g. `.../product/image/1234` or `.../productImages?productId=1234`) and returns the image. Then you could put that predictable URL into the `src` attribute of the `img`. How exactly you get the image binary data from the database into your HTTP response depends on the library you're using for your API. However it's not necessary to base64 encode it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way around that, you're just transferring the size of the image to the HTML instead.

I would recommend against storing images in a database, the correct way to do it would be to store the images on the file system and store the URL within the database.

That should keep your HTTP response small and the HTML will load fast.